# I cant access my server rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, port, ubuntu-14.04

Well as the title says i cant access my ruby on rails app, on the server i run the command:

```
rails s
```

After that everything works like it is suppose to work but it doesn't
When I enter my ip on my browser i put it like this x.x.x.x:3000 I have also tried x.x.x.x:3000/andtheurls

On my server i have run the command:

```
nmap localhost
```

To see if the port 3000 is opened, and it is.
My browser just tells me that it cant access the site and that my conexion has been rejected

I use and ubuntu 14.04 for my server

Comment: Have you tried `0.0.0.0:3000` ?

Comment: No, i want to use my public ip to access my server, im not on my localhost, im on a computer on my house and i want to set up a server somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what IP address you're trying to use, but the easiest way is just to type `localhost:3000` in your url bar.

By the way, this is the same as `127.0.0.1:3000`. You should realize that this isn't your actual public IP address, though. *Everyone's* local IP address is `127.0.0.1`: it is the loopback's interface address.

Comment: No, i want to use my public ip to access my server, im not on my localhost, im on a  computer on my house and i want to set up a server somewhere else

Comment: Does your service provider offer a public IP address? They are usually considerable more expensive.

Comment: I think so, how can i check that?

Comment: @JoseRamon you can also use something like [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) or [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me) for this. Free tools to create a public IP which forwards to your localhost.

Comment: Possible ways: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/536252/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-private-ip-address-or-a-public-ip-address/